# Solspace Tag on Multi Entry Pages

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I can't seem to get a list of tags for an entry in multi-entry view. According to the docs, this should work, but I get no output.  Anyone have any luck doing this or suggestions?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles"  status="not closed" limit="20"}

  <h1>{title}</h1>
  {exp:tag:tags
    entry_id="{entry_id}"
    backspace="2"
    orderby="relevance"
    sort="asc"
    limit="6"
  }
    <a href="{path='articles'}/tag/{websafe_tag}">{tag}</a>,{/exp:tag:tags}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: What version of Favorites are you using? What version of EE are you using? Do you get at least the {title} displayed?

Comment: Sorry... should have added versions. Most current of both (Tag 4.2.5 and EE 2.7.3).  Yes, title displays, tag loop yields nothing.

Comment: Have you tested the above on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code? I would also try adding dynamic="no", and maybe remove all parameters besides `entry_id=""` and `dynamic="no"` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I will mark this as solved. I actually didn't need an embed for it to work, but I did clear out the other parameters and it eventually worked.  For mention, dynamic="no" didn't make a difference. worked both ways.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tag loop needs to be an embed and passed the entry ID.

Comment: Nope, still not getting any output by moving the tag loop to an embedded template.